# My soldering iron only has one wire coming out from the top and it has a clip at the end. How do I power this?

Tags: ground, wire

Can't figure out why or what or how it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Photo. My guess is it's not a soldering iron.

Comment: It sounds like a voltage probe used in automotive. Post a picture.

Comment: It may be an electric etching pen. Whatever it is, it isn't a soldering iron.

Comment: It may be from a resistance soldering unit. These are used for joining metals and the other lead would be clipped to the workpiece.

Comment: Yeah I got it from a tool box from a high end mechanic it's custom made and has a wired coil through out the unit

Comment: Anyway I could wire it so it could be a soldering iron?

Comment: Whatever this thing is, it's not a soldering iron and won't be useful for general purpose soldering tasks. If it's a resistance soldering pen, that's definitely not something you want to be using with electronics.

Comment: @DillonJack  Woah! Easy there! Applying power to it can injure or even kill you. As others mentioned, it looks like a probe or welding device. It might also be some kind of magnetic pickup tool. Regardless, it doesn't look safe. If you want a soldering iron, there's tons of really cheap and decent ones all over Amazon and eBay.

Comment: The coil inside is likely some sort of consumable electrode. When the tip wears out you'd pull out more of it. But indeed this is no good for electronic soldering, this is for a machinist's shop. Get a standard soldering iron :)

Comment: lot of different things it might be apparently.  what's the resistance?  coil makes me think it is not just a simple probe.  i don't think the coils are for a consumable electrode- would be pretty awkward to use compared to a bare coil of the same.